# SQL distinct keyword issue

Tags: sql-server-2005, distinct

I am fetching data from two tables. but i am getting unwanted repeatation so i want the distinct keyword to get only distinct records but it did not work

```
SELECT distinct fb_event.id AS rid, fb_event.eventname AS sevntname,
     fb_event.location AS slocation, fb_event.startdate AS sstartdate,
     fb_event.enddate AS senddate,
                          cast(fb_event.CATEGORY as text) AS sCATEGORY, cast(fb_event.tags as text) AS stags,
                                              cast(fb_event.description as text) AS sdescription, 
                                            cast(fb_event.eventid as text) AS seventid,
                                            cast(fb_event.city as text) AS scity, cast(fb_event.venue as text) AS svenue,
                                            cast(fb_event.country as text) AS scountry, cast(fb_event.postalcode as text) AS spostalcode,
                                            cast(fb_event.keyword as text) AS skeyword,
                          cast(fb_userevents.userid as text) AS suserid,fb_event.longitude as long, fb_event.altitude as alt,fb_event.attending
     FROM fb_event INNER JOIN
     fb_userevents ON fb_event.eventid = fb_userevents.eventid order by fb_event.eventid
```

The error:
 Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

What I am missing. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must have **b_event.eventid** in your select list

Comment: Maybe you should use `Order By` in your query. Look at these article

Answer (score 0):

As astlander mentions, if you're ordering by a particular field, that field must be listed it in the select statement. Add *fb_event.eventid* to your select, and your select statement should be fine.

Comment: this is already includede:
cast(fb_event.eventid as text) AS seventid,

Comment: @Janu - as far as SQL Server is concerned, `cast(fb_event.eventid as text) <> fb_event.eventid`. Either change your order by to `ORDER BY cast(fb_event.eventid as text)`or add `fb_event.eventid` to your select.

Comment: Than you @Lieven, yes it might be. I will check it